# PHP mb_substr() call to undefined function

Tags: php, zend-framework, mbstring, php-7.0

I have hosted my zend apigility code in aws server, And i have getting mb_substr() function undefined error when basic password authentication. i have using php 7.0.30 and ubuntu 16.4. And error details are below

```
[Wed Aug 29 13:42:43 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: 
Call to undefined function Zend\Crypt\Password\mb_substr() in 
/var/www/html/8181/vendor/zendframework/zend-crypt/src/Password/Apache.php:128 
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/8181/vendor/zendframework/zend-authentication/src/Adapter/Http/ApacheResolver.php(165): 
Zend\Crypt\Password\Apache->verify('admin', '$apr1$Wgw6JqIq$...')
```

After some googled i have do some changes in php.ini file, just remove the semicolon front of module of php_mbstring and php_exif dll. but still i have getting same error only,

```
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll  #i have enable this and below one.
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
```

Can you pls help to get from this issue.

Thanks

Gopal R

Comment: wrong namespace?

Comment: Did you restart your server after making the changes to php.ini?

Comment: @TsV this source code is working properly in stage server.

Comment: @DirkScholten yes i have restart server.

Comment: @TsV can you pls give me some suggestion pls, about the namespace

Comment: @Kitta check php modules:  php -m | grep mstring, and try something simple with mb_strstr() or \mb_strstr().